# How to find whether Listview scrolled up or down in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to hide some view, when listview scrolled up and display that view again, when list view scrolled down.
I used

```
  private void ScheduleServiceList_ItemAppearing(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
        {           
            var currentItem = e.Item as VehicleService;
            double listviewheight = ScheduleServiceListView.Height;
            if (viewModel.VehicleServiceList[0].Id == currentItem.Id)
            {
                SearchEntryLayout.IsVisible = true;
                HeadingGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, -70, 0, 0);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Just a quick tip: xamarin viewcell has overridable onappearing and ondisapearing. Create yourviewcell:viewcell and you gonna know whats happening on the screen..

Comment: Can You Please give me some example on How to create viewCell ? I really don't know how to do that, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612406/7149454

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement)
{
    ....
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        return new MyListViewCellView(new List<int> {  ... /* ids to disable or other objects */ });
    })
};
```