# How to use x:Name of items in listView at codebehind?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to use x:Name of the stacklayout in listview at code behind in xamarin.forms?

```
 <ListView HasUnevenRows="true" HeightRequist="{Binding ListHeight}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
             <StackLayout>
                 <StackLayout x:Name="btnStack/>
             </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How to use `btnStack` at codebehind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to access templated elements by name and by whatever way you like, create a custom view that will serve You as a cell. And in the cell's code-behind you will be able to access everything by name. Your initial parent list will now look like:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" HeightRequest="{Binding ListHeight}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <user:MyViewCell/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Your brand new cell will look like:

**XAML**:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNameSpace.MyViewCell">
    <StackLayout x:Name="btnStack" Spacing="0">
        <Label x:Name="txtEvenMore"/>
    </StackLayout>

    </ViewCell>
```

**Code**:

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyViewCell
    {
        public MyViewCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //you can init your cells here
            InitCell(); //this is just for demo
        }

        public void InitCell()
        {
            //i can access my stack:
            btnStack.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            //and even more
            txtEvenMore.Text = "By name? Yes! :)";
        }

        //Now not for demo but in the real world:
        //We can set content according to your data from ItemsSource
        //This will act when you set your ListView ItemsSource to something valid
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            SetupCell();
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        }

        public void SetupCell()
        {
            //use data from ItemsSource
            var item = BindingContext as YourItemClass;
            if (item == null) return;

            txtEvenMore.Text = item.SomeTextProperty;
            //etc.. :)
        }

   }
 }
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

This link explain how access elements withn listview
ListView creates only one instance of each View Controls.
We cannot access View Controls inside ListView directly. can be accessed indirectly.

```
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">  
 <ListView x:Name="PersonListView" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default">  
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
     <DataTemplate>  
       <ViewCell>  
         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" Margin="10">    
           <Label Text="{Binding name}" />  
           <Label Text="{Binding phone}" />  
           <Label Text="{Binding age}" /> 
           <Button Text="Click to See" Clicked="DisplayData"/>  
         </StackLayout>  
       </ViewCell>  
     </DataTemplate>  
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
 </ListView>
```

```
 async void DisplayData(object Sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
   // access buttonclickhandler  
   var buttonClickHandler = (Button)Sender;  

   // access Parent Layout for Button  
   StackLayout ParentStackLayout = (StackLayout)buttonClickHandler.Parent;  

   // access first Label "name"  
   Label nameLabel = (Label)ParentStackLayout.Children[0];  

   // access second Label "phone"  
   Label phoneLabel = (Label)ParentStackLayout.Children[1];  

   // access third Label "age"  
   Label ageLabel = (Label)ParentStackLayout.Children[2];  

   string name = nameLabel.Text;  
   string phone = phoneLabel.Text;  
   string age = ageLabel.Text;  
   await DisplayAlert("Person Details", "Name is : " + name + ".\n Phone Number is: " + phone + "\n Age is : " + age, "OK");  
 }
```

https://www.xamarinpaul.com/2018/11/how-to-access-view-controls-inside-Xamarin-forms-ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

When you define x:Name in Xaml, the relevant variable is defined automatically.
So you can just use it as it was defined. Something like:

```
// StackLayout btnStack; // no need - it is defined already
var cnt = btnStack.Children.Count; // should be ok
```

Probably your problem is that in the line:

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="btnStack/>
```

you forgot the closing quote. It should be:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="btnStack" />
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Grisha ,I solved problem through MVVM.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is a ListView, there may be multiple StackLayouts. So what you need to do is give the ListView an x:Name property, and then you can access the items in the ListView using it's `ItemSource` property. Like so:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" HeightRequest="{Binding ListHeight}" x:name="myListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout>
                   <StackLayout />
               </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in your code-behind, simply access the items through `myListView.ItemsSource`.

If you really need to manipulate an individual `StackLayout` in the list view, then you should think about setting it up properly using MVVM pattern.