# How can I access x:name in the code behind in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

So I have a MasterDetails setup and what I want to achieve is the following:
If I select an Item in the Menu (MasterView), I see its results (DetailsView).
This DetailsView is a ListView with ViewCells. So far so good.
Now I want to navigate into the details of the DetailsPage content.
Let me show you the code of this:

**XAML - AssignmentListPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App.Views.AssignmentListPage"
         Title="Opdrachten">
<ListView x:Name="AssignmentsListView" Margin="20">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="20,0,0,0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label x:Name="myAssignments" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the code-behind file:

**C# - AssignmentListPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AssignmentListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AssignmentListPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            NavigateDetails();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            AssignmentsListView.ItemsSource = await 
    App.AssignmentManager.GetAssignmentsAsync();

        }

        public void NavigateDetails()
        {
            var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

            tap.Tapped += (s, e) => OnLabelClickedAsync();

            myAssignments.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);


        }

        public async Task OnLabelClickedAsync()
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new AssignmentDetailsPage());
        }

    }
```

The problem is that `myAssignments` in the code-behind gives me a "Cannot resolve symbol ... " error.

I've tried the following without success:

In the `NavigateDetails()` function I've replaced `myAssignments` with:

```
var asd = this.FindByName<Label>("myAssignments");

asd.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
```

I have also tried using `this`, so like:

```
this.myAssignments.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
```

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong? I cannot access the label.

Comment: Naming items inside of a template doesn't do anything.  You need to either attach your Gesture in the XAML or in code when you create the template.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607818/how-to-use-xname-of-items-in-listview-at-codebehind

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the comments here and what you're asking the code to do here. The `ItemTemplate` is a property of the ListView. In it you can define how it should visualize the items of your list. If you add 10 items to the list, the listview will use the template 10 times to generate the needed visualization. So even if your codebehind could access this `myAssignments` by it's x:Name (and it can't because the template is just a design), how could you expect it to know which one you need? Hope this gives some insights as to why it isn't working

Comment: @Knoop Thank you for the explanation. Your line 'how could you expect it to know which one you need' is exactly the problem I would face. It's all clear now and I resolved it as Jason suggested.

Comment: @Mirwais as I noted in a comment on Jason's answer I recommend you to look at Commanding. It might be a bit complicated but with Commanding you can get the full functionality you probably want using XAML (well of course the Command itself is code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a gesture recognizer in XAML

```
<Label x:Name="myAssignments" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnLabelClickedAsync" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried what I suggested and it worked (with some modifications in the code-behind. So it is not possible to do this in the code-behind? I am new to all of this, so thanks for all the info!

Comment: You could define the entire DataTemplate in the codebehind.

Comment: Oh ok, so I cannot do it partially. I need to define the entire thing in the codebehind. It makes sense, thank you again.

Comment: On a side note if you're going for the XAML approuch I would recommend looking into Commands instead of using the Tapped event. I have a feeling this implementation is working towards using the specific assignment that was tapped in the list, and navigate towards a detail page for that assignment. With commands you can set the CommandParameter to the list item in the DataTemplate and use that in the tap handling. It's a bit more complicated then this, but I assume you'll end up with a command implementation at some point.