# How to interact with views inside a CollectionView from an Event Handler (in the Xaml.cs code)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am trying to change the parameter "text" of a label with the value of the parameter "Duration" of a MediaElement view, both of them are children of the same parent (Grid), and that Grid is located inside a CollectionView. I want to change the parameter text when I click a frame (which is also a child of the same Grid parent).

```
<Grid
                            HeightRequest="145"
                            ColumnDefinitions="25*,75*"
                            RowDefinitions="21*,21*,24*,34*"
                            Padding="0"
                            RowSpacing="0">
                            <!--Only plays programmatically once, why? No idea-->
                            <xct:MediaElement
                                x:Name="mediaa"
                                Source="{Binding messageVoice}"
                                IsLooping="True"
                                KeepScreenOn="True"
                                AutoPlay="False"
                                ShowsPlaybackControls="False"
                                
                                HeightRequest="0"
                                WidthRequest="0"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="3">
                            </xct:MediaElement>
                            <Frame
                                x:Name="PlayFrame"
                                HasShadow="False"
                                CornerRadius="20"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                WidthRequest="40"
                                IsClippedToBounds="True"

                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Padding="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Image
                                    Source="play.png"

                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    HeightRequest="100">
                                </Image>
                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="Play_Tapped">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Frame>
<Label
                                Text="I want to change this property"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                FontAttributes="None"
                                FontSize="16"
                                    
                                Margin="15,0"
                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                Grid.Column="1">
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
```

Since all these views are located in a CollectionView I can't access to them using their x:names, The only way I have been able to extract information from them is by Executing a TapGestureRecognizer and accessing to copies of these views, but doing this I can only extract information, not change it:

```
void Play_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Frame frame = (Frame)sender;
            Grid parent = (Grid)frame.Parent;
            var audio = (MediaElement)parent.Children[0];
            audio.Play();
//I should change the text property here, but I couldn't do that since these views are just copies of the originals
        }
```

I know that I can bind a property to a property of a different view, but since the property duration is a TimeSpan? property, and text is a string property I have to do a proper conversion  before changing the text´s value.

Any Idea about how could I access these properties from the code behind (xaml.cs)?

Thank you all for your time, if you need any more information I will provide it to you as soon as I see your request.

Comment: bind the Label's Text property to a property of your model, and update your model when you want to update the Label.

Comment: @Jason is there any way to do it without binding its properties? I would have to use the ViewModel for interface purpose and I don't want to break the MVVM architecture

Comment: I don't see how that "breaks" MVVM.  Binding UI properties to the VM is an essential part of the pattern.  You could try binding the XAML elements directly to each other

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612406/7149454