# Clickable carouselview in xamarin.fourm

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a carouselview that works fine. all I want is when  clicking an image in this carouselview if the image name is "monthly.jpg" then display an alert or navigate or ...

my xaml code is as falow:

```xml
<CarouselView x:Name="CV">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame WidthRequest="400">
                <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    HeightRequest="240"
                    WidthRequest="300"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    Margin="10"
                    Padding="0">
                    
                    <Grid>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Image
                                Source="{Binding imgSource}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                ClassId="{Binding imgSource}"
                                HeightRequest="350">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired="1">

                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
    ....
```

and my code is:

```cs
private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string text = ((Image)sender).ClassId;

    Image image = (Image)sender;
    string imageString = image.ClassId;

    if (imageString == "monthly.jpg")
    {
        DisplayAlert("Go Go", "Please Try Egain", "Continue");
    }
}
```

but when I click an image nothing happen.
where am I wrong??
do I worked with classID correctly or what?

Comment: Is there any error or warning in VS Output, when that page appears, or when you tap the image? If you put a breakpoint at the start of TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped, is that breakpoint reached? (Or similarly, Debug.WriteLine some text, see if that appears in Visual Studio's Output pane.)

Comment: have you checked the actual value of `ClassId` in the debugger?  It likely isn't what you think it is.

Comment: No the Tapped never reached!

Comment: how to check it if the code never recognize Tapping?

Comment: is `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` defined in the code behind, or somewhere else?

Comment: its in the code behind.

Comment: you might try moving the gesture recognizer to the stack or grid instead of the image

Comment: If Jason's suggestion doesn't work, its time to try some tests to determine what exactly is causing this to break. I like to start with a simple test to make sure I am using the feature (here, TapGestureRecognizer) correctly. Make a template that just shows a colored box, and attach a tap to it: `<CarouselView.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <StackLayout> <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers><TapGestureRecognizer ...> </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers> <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" /> </StackLayout> </DataTemplate> ...` Does that reach Tapped method?

Comment: Hi all. I moved the gesture all over and it only works if I have a fixed image (not Binded) on carouselview or on the Grid. NOW the tap is reaching but the problem is I cant call the binding images from code behind by its name.

Comment: I mean that I cant use [[ (Image).sender]] or XImage.ClassId]]

Comment: I have this problem with all binding objects in listview, Carouselview....when you populate this with MVVM, You can not call these template objects by their names in code behind.

Comment: Show the modified code that *does* reach Tapped method. With breakpoint, what is value of `sender`? If it is a `StackLayout`, then in debugger, look at its `Children`. Is one of them the `Image`? You can get that image by `layout.Children.OfType<Image>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                        
                                         Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                                           
                                          NumberOfTapsRequired="1">

                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

Comment: no the sender is grid. it didnt work for layout.

Comment: now I can click the images, but  cant specify which binding image

Comment: look at the code man its the only grid in the post, 2 images, one of them is binding as you can see

Comment: (In the question, you only show one image. I also didn't ask which grid, I asked whether there was anything else beyond the StackLayout.) What I needed to know is what you have told me now: there is more than 1 image; you don't know which one got tapped, right? You'll need to do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48612406/199364), but using `<DataTemplate>` where it uses `ViewCell`. That is, make a new class, with XAML and code behind, with everything you now have inside `<DataTemplate>`. In *that* classes code behind, you may have more success putting Tap on each Image.

Comment: Sorry the code was too long to post completely. Is there a way the call any image in code behind as a child of a grid? the code dosent know Grid.Children.

Comment: Put an `x:Name` on each child, similar to the answer I just linked. HOWEVER those x:names (inside an item template) can ONLY be accessed if you make this new class I mentioned.

Comment: I tested the same code with my own itemsource. The image TapGestureRecognizer would be triggered. The ClassID works. Please check it whether the TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped event registed correctly.

Comment: Zang you are right the code is working, but it only works when I tap a specific position on picture!!!!!!! kill me now

Comment: Jesuses something wrong with my Hight request or ext.??? Never see something like this

Comment: The Tap works on anywhere of the image. I am not understand the specific position of the pictire. Could you provided more details for this?

Comment: all images are 500*400 pixel, The tap is triggered only on one of the images at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for All answers and time you spend to solve my problem. anyway I changed my Tapping gesture  to triggered at Grid and give my Grid Class ID. the program works now.

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var check = (Grid)sender;

            string imageString = check.ClassId;

            if (imageString == "daily check")
            {
                DisplayAlert("Day", "Please Try Egain", "Continue");
            }
```